# Appending user input to a list in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm new to python programming and I'm doing some experiments with it. Hoping my question is not too silly: I'm writing a little program that adds inputs to a list and print it when the input equals to 4, using a while loop. the problem is it never stops to add inputs and print the list.
My code is:

```
S=input()
L=[]
while S!=4:
    L.append(S)
    if S==4:
        break
print(L)
```

Comment: inputs are always of type `string`. when you type in `4` you are not adding `4` to the list but `"4"`. You have to cast it to `int` first. Like `int(input())`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: Thank you, with int(input()) works perfectly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've created an infinite loop in your code. You're not changing the value of S after you enter the loop. You should add get an another input from inside the loop like so:

```
S=input()
L=[]
while S!=4:
   L.append(S)
   S = input()
print(L)
```

In addition, The if condition in your code is useless since It's already set in the while loop declaration

Comment: Well, the loop keeps running until the users insert the number 4.  How exactly is this an infinite loop?

Comment: The input function returns strings, so S will never be an integer.

Comment: well in Python 3. input() does return a string, but in 2.7 it returns the type of whatever expression the user types in. I ran it on 2.7 and the python version is not specified in the question.

Comment: On SO  you should assume Python 3 if no version is specified. And the OP is probably using Python 3 from the look of that print call, although of course that's no guarantee. However, the Python 2 input function should be avoided for security reasons. Also, anyone starting on Python now really ought to be be learning 3, not 2.

Comment: Well, what I were doing is write a code that runs endlessly until I digit "4". I was just trying to understand how Python works. Thanks @itaisls9! And yes, I'm using Python 3

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Maybe I didn't understood thoroughly, can you explain me why? This solutio  has worked for me. also, I've commented other answeres that have worked too.

Comment: @Franz Then, you copied the wrong code. because S is a string, and it is never parsed to int before checking, the loop condition will never be true.

Comment: ah ok, in fact I've also corrected S = input() in S = int(input()), following the advices you can find in other users' answers. I cannot accept more than 1 answer as the solution to my problem, but  I've thanked them in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you one time read the input `S = 1` for example, after that `S` always 1 so `S` never be 4 and your loop is never stoop, you must add your input to `while`:

```
list = []
number = -1
while number != 4:
    number = int(input())
    list.append(number)
print(list)
```

And if you check that S != 4 in `while` you don`t need`if`statement in`while`.

Answer (score 1):

input() function returns string objects, so they can never be equal to 4 which is an int object.

To get out of the problem, replace `4` by `'4'`.

This will consider the `'4'` as a string as the equality will hold when you enter 4 as input

Answer (score 1):

There is another big problem with your code you don't update S anymore a more right answer would be:

```
S=input()
L=[]
while S!=4:
    L.append(S)
    if S=="4":
        break
    S = input()
print(L)
```

If you'd not want everything to block waiting for new input then you might consider throwing in threading but if it's just to allow the user to add values to an array and stop doing that by adding 4 this could help

Comment: This is with the int cast is offcourse if you want the array to contain int's, Which was not specificly mentioned by the creator