# print counting duplicate in table

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

i want to count duplicate and print it in table,

but the table iterating. how can i solve this assignment

this is my code

```
dummyString = "kamu makan makan jika saya dan dia??"
lists = []

def message(userInput):
    punctuation = "!@#$%^&*()_+<>?:.,;/"
    words = userInput.lower().split()
    conjunction = file.read().split("\n")
    removePunc = [char.strip(punctuation) for char in words if char not in conjunction]
    global lists
    lists = removePunc
    return removePunc

def counting(words):
    already_checked = []
    for char in words:
    # Do not repeat the words
        if char not in already_checked:
        # Check all the indices of the word in the list
            indices = [key for key, value in enumerate(words) if value == char]
            countsDuplicate = len(indices)
            table(lists, countsDuplicate)
        already_checked.append(char)

    return indices

def table(allWords, counts):
    print("Distribusi Frekuensi Kata: ")
    print("-"*70)
    print("{:>0s} {:<15s} {:<15s}".format("No","Kata","Frekuensi"))
    print("-"*70)
    words = set(allWords)
    count = 1
    for word in words:
        print("{:>0s} {:<20s} {:<10s}".format(str(count), word, str(counts)))
        count += 1
```

i want the output like this, but the table repeat many times

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
No Kata            Frekuensi
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1 makan                2
2 dia                  1
3 kamu                 1
4 saya                 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your words list is already cleaned up, e.g.

```py
words = "kamu makan makan jika saya dan dia??"
punctuation = "!@#$%^&*()_+<>?:.,;/"
for p in punctuation:
    if p in words:
        words = words.replace(p, '', words.count(p))
words = words.split()
```

you could use `set` in combination with `.count` and `sorted` to get a print-out of word and abundance in descending order:

```py
w_unq = sorted(((item, words.count(item)) for item in set(words)), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print('No.\tWord\tAbundance')
for i, u in enumerate(w_unq):
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(i+1, *u))
```

gives you

```
No.     Word    Abundance
1       makan   2
2       saya    1
3       dan     1
4       dia     1
5       jika    1
6       kamu    1
```

Comment: i'm still new learning python so i don't know how to use lambda, but it works and Thank you so much !!

Comment: happy to help! there's a lot of tutorials on Python's `lambda` out there, just hack it into google... here, it is passed to the `sorted` function telling it to sort  by the second element (at index 1; `x[1]`) of each element of the iterable to be sorted. In your specific case, that is the number of occurances of a certain word.

Comment: can i ask you again? This is about that assignment. I want my code take an input, the input not stoping until i enter empty string, and the table will print in the final output that store all the input

Comment: I suppose you want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975837/appending-user-input-to-a-list-in-a-loop). Basically call `input` in a `while` loop (that you `break` if the return of `input` e.g. has a length of zero), append inputs to a list, then clean the words in the list, do the sorting and the printing.

Comment: this is my new question with the latest code https://stackoverflow.com/q/58398538/12208516

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is remove the punctuations from dummyString, find the word count and display them in a dataframe.

The below code should work for you:

```py
import string
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

dummyString = "kamu makan makan jika saya dan dia??"
dummyString_new=dummyString.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

words = dummyString_new.split()
wordCount = Counter(words)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wordCount, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns=['No Kata','Frekuensi']
df.index += 1                         # to start your index from 1 and not 0.
```

**Output:**

df:

```py
    No Kata Frekuensi
1   kamu       1
2   makan      2
3   jika       1
4   saya       1
5   dan        1
6   dia        1
```

Comment: Thank you, but my assignment have a rule not to use dictionary and counter, sorry my question not very clear that my assignment have a rule, but thank you for answering